# How can I create Google(Android)-style images?

Tags: windows, drawing, vector-graphics, graphic-design

I'm trying to achieve this style:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Notice that I'm talking only about the **imagery** of the screenshots, I'm not talking about Material Design. This style they're using seems really minimalist and simple, with simple color palette and reduced lines, yet is has depth and is intricate when you pay attention to detail. What is a suggested tool to create similar graphics? I realize that I'd probably need vector design software, but I'm not sure which one. Can you recommend me one?

The price doesn't matter, I'm using Windows 7, I'm designing for Android.

Answer (score 1):

### Specific recommendations

I am using [InkScape](https://inkscape.org/en/) whenever I need a freeware tool and I have bought [CorelDraw](http://www.coreldraw.com/us/) for myself. I find CorelDraw has some more features and some bugs less.

Both tools provide layer support so you can focus on individual items and hide objects that are in your way. Once you have e.g. the phone design, you can import, link or copy/paste it to new images, thus minimizing your work.

### General

While vector drawings can basically be made of any color, it is hard to make photo realistic drawings. Therefore probably any tool will suit your need regarding color palette. Vector drawings are scalable by design, so any tool should be able to zoom in and modify details.

Depending on the development stage (maybe not choose an alpha version) and the number of bugs, just find one which is comfortable for you. The [Comparison table in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_vector_graphics_editors) might help on that.

Maybe you want to make a list of features and requirements that are mandatory for you. From those given in this question, my guess would be that any vector drawing tool fits.

Comment: So, you're suggesting that (from what you've described) any vector graphics tool will get the job done?

Comment: @AleksandarStefanović: yes, that's what I believe. I have updated the answer.